# Running PowerShell script on a remote machine using PSTool

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I need to run a PS script on a remote machine, am doing as in the below code.

```
Process psExecer = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = @"c:\PsTools\PsExec.exe",
                    Arguments = @"c:\windows\System32\cmd.exe /k  c:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe E:\Scripts\SetUP.ps1 -u super -p Pass -s"        
                }
            };

            psExecer.Start();
            psExecer.WaitForExit();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

problem is that script has some sharepoint cmdlets and it has to load sharepoint PSSnapin. Script runs properly only when its run in 64 bit image of Powershell.

When i tried to run using PSTool, PSTool always ends up invoking 32 bit PowerShell from %windir%\SysWoW64 folder, even when i explicitly mentioned the path as shown in the code.

Why is it so, what is the solution to my problem

Regards,
Jeez

Comment: Just curious, but why do you load `cmd` then get that to load `powershell`, rather than running `powershell` directly?

Comment: Tried directly loading powershell gave same error, so tried loading using cmd which was not of much use

Comment: I'm assuming it's a typo, but you state you need to run the 64-bit version of powershell, but then load it from `System32`. Can you update your question to make sure there's no confusion...?

Comment: any full source code with final solution working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a 32-bit app references c:\windows\System32 it's redirected to SysWoW64

Try using c:\windows\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Comment: Jako you are right, I was facing the issue because the PsTool is a 32 bit application and hence always 32 bit powershell was being called.Thanks a lot for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you invoke is the side effect of the process virtualisation due to UAC.

Here are three solutions:

**1. Remove UAC on the target computer**

**2. WinRM**

If you want to remote execute PowerShell scripts on targets like Windows 2008 R2 and Windows Seven, the best way  is to use WSMan just have a look to `about_Remote` help In PowerShell.

**3. try to remove virtualisation on the process you invoke on the remote computer**

To prevent virtualization, add a manifest in the same directory as the EXE file for which you want to remove virtualisation. A manifest is an XML file named `yourexename.exe.manifest`. [You can find in this site a manifest sample](http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/manifest-template). Try to set the `requestedPrivileges` to `asInvoker`.