# Is it possible to get user credentials from AD and use it to run some app with that credentials?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, credentials

I want to control thinreg.exe util via powershell script. This util is used for registering vmware thinapp packages on the system(it creates shorcuts and add registry entries under HKCU hive.)
If I run my ps script as admin then also thinreg runs under admin account and register app to the admin. 
So it is possible to get user credentials from AD and use them to run PS script or just thinreg util ? 
I'm domain admin and other users are domain users. AD is win 2008r2 and client OSes are winXP sp3.

Thank you very much.

---

### EDIT

Is it possible to install windows service via login script so that would run under logged user account ? 
Via this service I could then control thinreg.exe util

Comment: You can get the user name and other bits from AD - but you can **never** get the password for a user. I would prompt the user for his password when you run your app - and preferably don't store it anywhere!

Comment: Prompting user for his pass isn't good solution, because most of them will just igore it and other will cal help desk that some app wants their password.

Comment: I know I can't get user's pass and I even don't want to get it. But I hoped that I can get user hashed pass and use this hash.

Comment: If you could do that, what would be the point of the password?

Comment: Normal users don't have access to AD and since AD is nothing more than storage for various informations I thought I could access user's username and pass hash.

Answer (score 0):

I would try two ways.

1. Add the powershell script run once during the logon script of the user
2. If user are using roming profiles, try to modify their profiles when they are logged off.

If you want to be more "interactive", and do it as the user is log in, you can try to play with PSTOOLS you can have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715049/running-powershell-script-on-a-remote-machine-using-pstool) to have an example how to call your powershell script from PSTOOLS.

Comment: Curently I have like you suggested at first point. But I seek for more interative way.

Comment: Is it possible to install windows service via login script so that would run under logged user account ? 
Via this service I could then control thinreg.exe util

Comment: I don't think you can install service to run as a user unless you can supply credentials for that user when you install it.

Comment: What do you mean by "more interative" way? What is that you don't like about this method, that you want to improve?

Comment: It was typo, I meant "interactive". I would like to control this util even when the user is logged into the computer.

Comment: PStools doesn't solve the problem. Problem is not how to reach the desired machine but how to impersonate user currently logged onto that machine.